# Failed to execute job because of not registered Spark workers

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

When I try to execute Spark SQL query on GCP Dataproc cluster I'm seeing an error:

> Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

I have checked my worker nodes and they are 95% available, still I am facing this issue.

In some other post I got an advice to free up the worker nodes, can anyone let me know how to free up worker nodes in GCP?

Comment: May you share a command that you use to create Dataproc cluster and submit Spark SQL job?

Comment: Commands use is as below:

gcloud beta dataproc clusters create cluster-3316 --enable-component-gateway --bucket xxxxxxxx --region us-west1 --subnet default --zone us-west1-a --single-node --master-machine-type n1-standard-4 --master-boot-disk-size 50 --image-version 1.3-deb9 --optional-components ANACONDA,JUPYTER --project maximal-muse-251207 --initialization-actions gs:xxxxxxxxxENV.bash

Answer (score 0):

You are using a single node cluster (as mentioned in the comment) which most probably doesn't have enough resources to run your query.

To confirm this, you can create cluster with at least 2 worker nodes. To do so you need to remove `--single-node` parameter from your cluster creation command.